# How can I encode audio from AudioRecord in real-time using FFmpeg in Android?

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I have raw PCM bytes in byte[] buffer and I am trying to encode them in different formats using FFmpeg in real-time. Which command is used to do this? 
I can convert wav audio file to mp3 file using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f mp3 output.mp3
```

but how can I convert raw PCM bytes and save them in real-time in different formats such as mp3? I have not found the answer any where on the internet till now. Please help me.

Comment: what is the code that you tried? you must Compile the FFmpeg for Android and then use NDK for load the library in your project. [Check this link](http://www.roman10.net/2011/07/17/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/)

Comment: this https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android

Comment: 's link also will help you to compile the ffmpeg. Then you need a filedescriptor to implement a format covertor